# I need to fetch data from database and display in my view using php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am fetching the data from the database.But I am getting error.Here I need to display product name and image in the page.But I am getting the error undefined variable 'name' in the page. Please check my code give your valuable suggestions,Thank you.

My controller

```
<?php

    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class productdisplay_ctrl extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->model("productdisplay_model");
        }

        public function productfetch(){

            $this->load->model("productdisplay_model");
            $result = $this->productdisplay_model->fetchData();
            $data['name'] = $result->sub3_category_name;

            $this->load->view('home', $data);
        }

    }

?>
```

my model

```
<?php

    class productdisplay_model extends CI_Model {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function fetchData() {

            $this->db->where($where);
            $this->db->order_by('rand()');
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('sub3_category');
            $query = $this->db->get();

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                    $data[] = $row;
                }

                return $data;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

?>
```

my view

```
<div class="container-main">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="prod-container">
      <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/productlist">
        <div class="prod_img">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/img-electronics.jpg" width="100%"/>
        </div>
        <div class="prod_desc">
          <div class="prod-round-icon"></div>
          <h4 class="prod_title"><?php echo $name; ?></h4>
          <p class="prod_text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="view-more"> view more</div>
      </a>  
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is the contents of the `$result` variable after `$result = $this->productdisplay_model->fetchData();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in model.like this.use `row()` which returns result in object format having matched row.so that you can access columns using arrow operator.

And what about your `$where` variable.set it.

```
public function fetchData() {

            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->where($where);
            $this->db->order_by('rand()');
            $this->db->from('sub3_category');
            $query = $this->db->get();

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

                return  $query->row();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Controller

```
            defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

            class productdisplay_ctrl extends CI_Controller {

                public function __construct() {
                    parent::__construct();

                    $this->load->helper('url');
                    $this->load->model("productdisplay_model");
                }

                public function productfetch(){

                    $this->load->model("productdisplay_model");
                    $result = $this->productdisplay_model->fetchData();
                    $data['name'] = $result->sub3_category_name;

                    $this->load->view('home', $data);
                }

            }

        ?>
```

Model:

```
    <?php

        class productdisplay_model extends CI_Model {

            function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
            }

            public function fetchData() {

              $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->where($where);
                $this->db->order_by('rand()');
                $this->db->from('sub3_category');
                $query = $this->db->get();

                if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

                    return  $query->row();
                }
                return false;
            }

        }

    ?>
```

view:

```
<div class="container-main">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="prod-container">
      <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/productlist">
        <div class="prod_img">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/img-electronics.jpg" width="100%"/>
        </div>
        <div class="prod_desc">
          <div class="prod-round-icon"></div>
          <h4 class="prod_title"><?php echo $name; ?></h4>
          <p class="prod_text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="view-more"> view more</div>
      </a>  
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the foreach loop, remember $row var is a object

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row->field;
            }
```